# Sort kills the program : MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I wrote the following program in order to get an array of strings from user, sort them and then show the sorted array to the user.

But it seems that the `sort` function kills the program completely. Because the second `msgbox` never appears.

Also note that if I cancel the `inputdlg` in the first time it appears, both message boxes appear.

```
strings = {};
count = 1;
while(1)
    prompt = {strcat('Enter the ', num2str(count), '# String')};
    temp = inputdlg(prompt,'Input String',1,{'String'});
    if isempty(temp)
        break
    end   
    strings{count} = temp;
    count = count + 1;
end
msgbox('Processing....');
sorted = sort(strings); % The program stops executing on this point
msgbox('Operation Completed');
```

**So why the program never executes the last line?** Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Also, you should provide a complete executable example (i.e. [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: I think the "sort" function kills the program, but I want it to continue its work. In other words: "Why the second msgbox is never displayed?" Edit: This is an executable example and works fine when I run it in editor (Except the problem I mentioned)

Comment: Update your question with that statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `temp` is a 1x1 cell containing the entered string. By assigning `strings{count} = temp`, each entry of `strings` is a 1x1 cell. If you look at the variable in the Workspace, you'll be able to verify that. You can access the entered string only by calling

```
strings{count} = temp{1};
```

With this modification, the `strings` cell contains strings and not cells. Now you will be able to sort the cell with the `sort` function and your code should work as expected.

Comment: beat me to it... was just typing a similar answer, note that as strings is initialised as a cell (`strings = {};`) then using `strings(count) = temp;` is an alternative